# Nginx config for Restful API behind proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to move my node proxy from port `8080` to `80` and hitting walls.
I want my RESTful API to be behind a nginx reverse-proxy listening on port 80 on location `/api/path` instead.

*(Port `8080` wasn't accessible for some enterprise users behind overzealous firewalls.)*

I used to direct requests to https://domain.tld:8080/ to http://localhost:1337. No problems via:

```
server {
    listen      8080;
    server_name  domain.tld;

    ssl on; #some other SSL config removed for clarity

    location / {
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_pass_header       Server;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_connect_timeout   5;
        proxy_read_timeout      240;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;

        proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:1337;
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to move it to location `api/path/` and away from port `8080` via:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name  domain.tld;
    root         /path/to/html/;

    ssl on; #some other SSL config removed for clarity

    location /api/path/ {
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_pass_header       Server;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_connect_timeout   5;
        proxy_read_timeout      240;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;

        proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:1337;
    }
}
```

This results in:

```
$ curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d '{}' https://domain.tld/api/path

TTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 08 Sep 2016 01:29:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 25
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;

Cannot POST /api/path
```

Now I read that you can't POST to static pages which means you do something like:

```
error_page  405          @405;

location = @405 {
    root         /path/to/html/;
}
```

But as I can't find enough infos about this it's not working. GET works as normal but POST will error out with `Cannot POST api/path`. What can I do here?

Appreciate any help.

### Update

I needed to enable the `proxy_redirect` as @techraf pointed out so my successful config looks like this now. Hope it helps someone.

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name  domain.tld;
    root         /path/to/html/;

    ssl on; #some other SSL config removed for clarity

    location /api/path/ {
        proxy_redirect          http://localhost:1337/  /api/path/; #<-- change
        proxy_pass_header       Server;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_connect_timeout   5;
        proxy_read_timeout      240;
        proxy_intercept_errors  on;

        proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:1337;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant and I used it to replace an HAProxy instance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68495693/creating-an-api-proxy-using-haproxy-and-getting-responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to point `/api/path/` to the root of your redirect destination, you need to use:

```
proxy_redirect http://localhost:1337 https://domain.tld/api/path/
```

Comment: The port `8080` is to be phased out and be replaced by the port `80` path. So users instead of hitting `domain.tld:8080` should hit `domain.tld/api/path` via POST and GET. So `8080` redirects are not really important to me right now.

Comment: After you edited your answer: Can I do something like this then: `proxy_redirect https://domain.tld/api/path/ http://localhost:1337`?

Comment: yeah sorry, hard to ask. Thanks for the answer, let me test and get back.

Comment: So when I set nginx to `location /api/path/ { proxy_redirect https://domain.tld/api/path/ http://localhost:1337; }` my `curl` returns a 404 error for `https://domain.tld/api/path/`

Comment: With the rest on I get back to the `Cannot POST /api/path` error :(

Comment: That throws a 405...

Comment: Thanks @techraf. Your directive was the wrong side around which is why it was failing. After research I just fixed it and added the solution to the question. I'd be happy to mark your answer as correct once you turn those parameters around :)